# Execute method in viewmodel when property changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have some `ViewModel` with string property `Name`

My `ViewModel` inherit from `ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
...
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetField(ref _name, value, "Name"); }
    }

...

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
    }
}
```

I want to execute some logic when my property `Name` change its value (on user input). My ViewModel will have alot of such properies and i will have alot of ViewModels with same property processing.

How should i run method that process chaneged propery in a right way?
Should i subscribe on `PropertyChanged` event in my ViewModel, then use `switch` on string property name to detect actual changed property and then use it value?
Or should i just run my method from setter?

Is there any patterns for such interactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your SetField method returns true if the property has changed, I would call my method in the setter if true is returned.

```
...
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set 
    { 
        if (SetField(ref _name, value, "Name"))
            MyMethod();
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I understand that i can do it in such way, but i dont understand is it right in terms of MVVM? If i get it right, my property shoud contain no logic and act like they know nothing about rest of viewmodel? Or i am wrong?

Comment: While MVVM mainly intends to separate logic that interacts with data and logic to interact with your UI, it does not mean you should follow this *by the book*. While you could achieve what you want using commands in your vm and then executing them with property changed triggers in XAML I find that it's not the cleanest solution, in terms of readability. In my opinion, clarity should not be sacrificed for the sake of MVVM purity.